# Hate the new black top bar? Kill it with StyleBot

Tags: discussion, top-bar

I was really disappointed with the recently introduced black top bar. It really doesn't fit the math.stackexchange theme!

Hence I installed the free [StyleBot extension](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CEMQFjAA&url=https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha&ei=eFSjUv6FC6WW0AXFsYDwCA&usg=AFQjCNGVQxs1GX5mc5uxmtGJuLihFiwU6A&sig2=MLPTrO5AJQfH8b-jPR0SKg&bvm=bv.57752919,d.d2k) to Chrome, and then I created [this layout](http://stylebot.me/styles/4296), which just kills the horrible black bar. Here's the result:

[image]

Hope you like it!

If you modify the style or create a new one, please share it here.

PS: Yes, it works on the meta too `;-)`

**UPDATE:** Now the SE Logo at the top is fixed. Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: We want one for firefox too!! :P

Comment: I’m not terribly keen on the new look, but I much prefer it to using Chrome! (And I expect that I’ll get used to it before too awfully long.)

Comment: I'm not that terribly fond of it, myself (actually, I hate it, like you!) I've got an astigmatism that makes reading light font on a darker background (white on black, or the dreaded white on green, e.g.) particularly difficult for me. (Do web developers/programmers take such things into consideration? I think humans read more readily and have less impairments when print is dark on a light background!) In any case, I can't readily access information that I was able to in the prior version. But like @BrianM.Scott, I suspect I'll get more used to it, save for the literal "eyesore".

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: What do you have against Chrome? Really, since I'm using it I'm curious to know

Comment: nice,  but how to get rid of it again?

Comment: @Abramo: Probably mostly habit: I’ve been using Firefox since about version $0.7$. I tried Chrome on MSE for a while, but (a) I never felt entirely comfortable with it, and (b) MSE tabs in Chrome crashed too often when I was writing answers.

Comment: Well, I'm not using it from a long time, but I'm pretty happy about it. Probably it got much better nowadays! I thought you were against it because of the Google quasi-monopoly and the fact that they retain all of your personal data.

Comment: @Abramo: That actually is part of it; I’m less and less happy with Google, though for the moment at least I’m still using Gmail.

Comment: @Abramo : I hate the new black bar too, but I use Firefox, and I've heard a lot of bad things about Chrome.  Do you foresee this being done for Firefox?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : you might want to consider inbox.com . Unlike gmail, you can create folders, and they don't group your messages into confusing "conversations" without your asking like gmail does (but you can do this if you want).  Unlike Yahoo Mail, there seem to be very few ads.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks; I may look into it. (The ‘conversations’ aren’t actually much of a problem, since I download everything to my own mail client; gmail’s storage is just a backup for me. I concur with your opinion of the organization, though!)

Comment: @Brian M.Scott : Google doesn't seem to follow their own motto "Don't be evil."  They operate in China and filter out search results that offend the totalitarian regime there.  I know there are many other big Internet firms that refuse to do business with Red China (sorry I can't name them at the moment). They donate money to ultra-right-wing political activist groups.  They are famous for gathering and hoarding all the personal data they can about their users.

Comment: Everybody: starting today or yesterday or so, I see both the ugly black bar and the classic Mathematics and Mathematics meta logos at the top.  I didn't do anything to Firefox, it just happened.  I can live with the ugly little black bar as long as the classic logo is there too.

Comment: Dear @Abramo, how did you fix the SE logo so that "Stack" stays black?

Comment: @Andrew: You need to insert in the CSS for ".topbar .icon-site-switcher" the line "background-position: 10px -50px !important;". This will pick the alternative logo from this image: http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/topbar-sprite.png

Comment: @amWhy, actually, people with different reading-related disabilities (color-blindness, blurry vision, difficulty with bright colors, difficulty with high contrast, difficulty with low contrast, dyslexia in various forms, etc., etc.) have radically different and often-incompatible needs. General good practice: make sure the website will play reasonably well with a user's custom stylesheets, and optimize for the common case (which grey on black *definitely* fails to do).

Answer (score 3):

In the comments, some users asked about a Firefox analog of the above. A popular Firefox extension for managing user stylesheets is [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/). Several stylesheets for the top bar, some specifically designed for Firefox, can be found at [Gallery of custom styles and/or scripts for the top-bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210041).

Apart from extensions, most of today's browsers  have built-in support for user stylesheets. [This guide](http://webdesign.about.com/od/userstylesheets/) has the browser-specific details.

Perhaps as an overreaction to the Big Black Bar, I now use a [simple stylesheet](http://pastebin.com/2pwwTc82) with toned-down appearance and hidden  "StackExchange" name:

[image: topbar]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modification for MSE of phils's answer in Post No Bills's link. This works with "Stylish" on Firefox:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("stackexchange.com")
               /* domain("mathoverflow.net") /* for MO */
{
  .topbar,
  .topbar .icon-achievements.icon-achievements-unread,
  .topbar .icon-achievements .unread-count {
    color: #999 !important;
    background: #f1f7fe none !important;
    /* background: #eee none !important; /* for MO */
  }
  .topbar .topbar-icon:hover,
  .topbar .topbar-icon-on,
  .topbar .topbar-icon-on:hover,
  .topbar .topbar-links .profile-me:hover,
  .topbar .topbar-links .topbar-menu-links a:hover,
  .topbar .icon-achievements.icon-achievements-unread:hover .unread-count {
    background-color: #bcd4e6 !important;
    /* background-color: #f38810 !important; /* for MO */
  }
  .topbar .icon-achievements,
  .topbar .icon-achievements .unread-count,
  .topbar .topbar-links .topbar-menu-links a,
  .topbar .topbar-links .topbar-menu-links a:visited,
  .topbar .topbar-links .topbar-flair .reputation,
  .topbar .topbar-links .topbar-flair .badgecount {
    color: #737373 !important;
  }
  .topbar .avatar-me {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .topbar .topbar-links .search-container input[type="text"] {
    border-color: inherit !important;
  }
  .topbar .icon-site-switcher {
    /* background-position: 11px 11px !important;
    /* background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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) !important; */
    background-position: 10px -50px !important;
  }
}
```

And a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Very nice, but I would add `mathoverflow.net` to the list of domains. It's probably more relevant to MSE users than serverfault.

Comment: Dear @PostNoBills, good point! I just noticed this as I went over to mathoverflow. However, the colour schemes don't match, so I've modified them to create another (almost the same) style sheet for MO. I will comment in the MO colours I've chosen.

Comment: Why not putting a nice shadow under the top bar? It can be done with "box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1px #eee;"